# Groundwater "GMS-MODFLOW" Transient Model

Tags: groundwater

I have transient model with domain 200*200m and consists of 5 layers with 45 stress period, first layer is alluvium and the other 4 layers are weathered rock will be solved using traditional MODFLOW GMS.

 The domain is restricted by head boundaries "head drop", when I check for simulation, the model gives some errors for cells at boundaries for the first layer, because of the head drop gives elevation lower than the first layer bottom elevation, 

 for example ( (for particular cell at transient boundary in the first layer)
cell top elevation = 500m and lower elevation is 490m and the transient head is linear starting from 498 to 450 over the 45 stress period

 when trying to attempt a run with head drop lower than the bottom elevation (as previously illustrated) of the first layer cells, the model can't complete all stress periods and stop running

how can I solve this problem as I have to maintain the same head drop??

 any help